# Merging two dataframes, then revoving duplicate observations WITHOUT removing yearly observations from same variable

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I am trying to analyze MLB player Salaries and create a machine learning model as my first project.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have discovered a fatal flaw in my dataframe. Upon merging the two dataframes I wanted to use, a player would be represented in ONE year for HOWEVER many years he was in the league, but it would be like that for each year too, meaning If a player was in the league for 7 years, his batting stats + salary would show up 7 times for each 7 years he was in the league (47 observations instead of 7 for each player).

I was purusing the site and couldn't quite find an answer that could help me with this problem, at least one I didn't get error's in trying to use.

Here are the two dataframes im trying to merge

Here is The code leading up to it.

````
FullName=pd.read_csv('core/People.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
FullName['Name']= FullName['nameFirst']+' '+FullName['nameLast']
FullName=FullName[['playerID','Name']]
FullName

experiment = pd.merge(FullName, SalariesCSV, on=['playerID'])

# This merge went fine, this one is not the issue

FullDataSet1= pd.merge(experiment, batting, on=['Name'])

#this is where the issue is!```



I have also tried this 

    dfNew = experiment.merge(batting, left_on=['Name', 'yearID'], right_on=['Name', 'Season'], validate="1:1")

but I kept getting this error

"Merge keys are not unique in either left or right dataset; not a one-to-one merge"

I am trying to merge these two datafrtames so that players are represented once every year they played along with that associated salary/batting stats. 



https://i.gyazo.com/dfc66f21e5cd286eb5f013fa571c371c.png
https://i.gyazo.com/ea5bc91dfbd72617fd82672a85d55b93.png
````

Answer (score 0):

```
    dfNew = experiment.merge(batting, left_on=['Name', 'yearID'], right_on=['Name', 'Season'], validate="1:1")
```

is really close, but mid-season trades happen. Try:

```
    dfNew = experiment.merge(batting, left_on=['Name', 'yearID', 'teamID'], right_on=['Name', 'Season', 'Team'], validate="1:1")
```

You might need to create a mapping between `teamID` and `Team`.

If this doesn't work, then there might be different players with the same name on same team, same season. It should be one offs, so you can solve these issues by hand.

Comment: That's exactly what it was Balbok, I have since figured it out thanks to some extremely helpful people.

For future readers, if you are playing with MLB data, especially when cross comparing two differen't databases, fix the teamIDs so that each databse has the same abbreviations for each team. I did this, narrowed down the duplicates through a function, and removed the duplicates. It was less than 10 out of 3000+ observations. You shoould be fine to remove some observations such as these. Once you drop them from the dataframe then you can merge using the function Balbok mentioned.